# Apply string suffix with custom formatter

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, eureka-forms

When working with `Swift`'s `Formatter` class, there is an option to choose a formatting style (energy, length, mass etc.) which will show at the end of the field, like in the example below:

[image]

I am building a form using the [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) framework and trying to achieve the same effect but to replace the "cal" suffix with "hours".

So the final results should be like "10 hours".

I am using Eureka's `IntRow` which only accepts Int values.

After some search, I managed to find a way to achieve this with a custom formatter which can be assigned to the `IntRow`, but it is not fully working. When I try to change the field's value, the field becomes empty with no values.

Custom formatter code:

```swift
class NumberSuffixFormatter: Formatter {

    var suffix: String!

    init(suffix: String = "") {
        self.suffix = suffix
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
       if let intValue = obj as? Int {
            return "\(intValue) hours"
        }
        return nil
    }

    override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

        obj?.pointee = string as AnyObject

        return true
    }
}
```

`IntRow` code:

```swift
<<< IntRow() {
    let formatter = NumberSuffixFormatter(suffix: " hours")
    $0.value = 10
    $0.formatter = formatter
    $0.useFormatterDuringInput = true
}
```

Comment: Looking through the Eureka project it looks like `obj?.pointee` might be expecting an `NSNumber`

Comment: Trying to change `AnyObject` to `NSNumber` results in a compile error. `obj?.pointee` expect `AnyObject`. Thanks.

Comment: Create an NSNumber from your string and then pass it using `as AnyObject`

Comment: "Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'NSNumber' always fails"